# Deploying GWT/GWTP app in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, gwt, gwtp

i know this might not directly be programming related. I hope it fits in here anyhow. 
I have a GWTP web app that runs perfectly fine in dev mode either from eclipse or from the command prompt running mvn gwt:run.
Now i try to deploy it to Tomcat 7 locally. I ran gwt:compile and copied the zip file (after renaming it to .war) to the webapps folder. The app is listed in Tomcat's manager gui. But when i try to navigate to localhost:8080/appname or localhost:8080/appname/Project.html, i only get an 404 error. What did  i miss?
For completeness, here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>testproject</groupId>
<artifactId>testme-gwtp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>GWTP Basic</name>
<description>Basic GWTP application</description>

<properties>
    <!-- client -->
    <gwt.version>2.6.0</gwt.version>
    <gwtp.version>1.2.1</gwtp.version>
    <gin.version>2.1.2</gin.version>

    <!-- server -->
    <guice.version>3.0</guice.version>

    <!-- testing -->
    <junit.version>4.7</junit.version>
    <jukito.version>1.4</jukito.version>

    <!-- maven -->
    <gwt-maven-plugin.version>2.6.0</gwt-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.6</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>2.5</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <maven-processor-plugin.version>2.0.5</maven-processor-plugin.version>
    <maven-build-helper-plugin.version>1.7</maven-build-helper-plugin.version>


    <target.jdk>1.7</target.jdk>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
</properties>

<build>
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <!-- JUnit Testing - skip *.GwtTest cases -->
        <!-- 'mvn test' - runs the Jukito tests -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*GwtTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- GWT -->
        <!-- 'mvn gwt:run' - runs development mode -->
        <!-- 'mvn gwt:debug' - runs debug mode -->
        <!-- 'mvn gwt:compile' - compiles gwt -->
        <!-- 'mvn integration-test' - runs the gwt tests (*GwtTest.java) -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- With multiple tests use GwtTestSuite.java for speed -->
                <includes>**/*GwtTest.java</includes>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xss1024K -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M</extraJvmArgs>

                <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
                <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>

                <runTarget>Project.html</runTarget>
                <modules>
                    <module>testproject.Project</module>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Google Web Toolkit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GWT-Platform -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtp-all</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>${guice.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${guice.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
        <version>${guice.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
        <version>${gin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jukito</groupId>
        <artifactId>jukito</artifactId>
        <version>${jukito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- hSQLDB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- add slf4j interfaces to classpath -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--  GWT-Log -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.allen-sauer.gwt.log</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-log</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>                   
</dependencies>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: From the listing of deployed apps on tomcat admin console, could you click the app on list and find the exact url where it is deployed? At least on glassfish (although different server type) you can find direct link to the app from clicking it. You don't have to guess it manually.

Comment: You can follow a link to the app, but in this case it is the one i tried: http://localhost:8080/myapp/

Comment: Is there anything on logs before deploy finishes?

Comment: That is all fine: Server startup in ... ms, Reloading context has started and is completed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `gwt-maven-plugin` **goals** is not bound to any maven **phases**. Try something like this:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate how this could influence the behaviour of the webapp in the tomcat server? Compile works fine, it seems.

Comment: I guess the gwt-maven-pugin isn't triggered during compilation. So you get 404 error because of the missing GWT artifacts in output.

Answer (score 0):

I addition to get it running, you need to do as Vadim told, but also this must be added to pom.xml:

```
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.4.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>resources</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>i18n</goal>
                                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                                        <goal>test</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

If you specify the phase for compile as `<phase>prepare-package</phase>`, it is perfomed as the last step before packaging when calling `mvn package`.